# How to use the 2015 IRC Chapter 24, G2407.6.2 to determine combustion air?

Tags: hvac, code-compliance, gas

The 2015 International Residential Code (IRC), Chapter 24 ("Fuel Gas"), [Section G2407.6.2](http://codes.iccsafe.org/app/book/content/2015%20San%20Antonio/2015%20IRC%20HTML/Chapter%2024.html) allows for one permanent opening to be used to supply outdoor combustion air into a mechanical room for gas appliances. How is the area of opening calculated for a gas furnace and gas water heater with a total input of 140,000 Btu/h?

How do you check that the calculated area is "not less than the sum of the areas of all vent connectors in the space"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2407.6.2 requires the opening to have a minimum free area of 1 in.<sup>2</sup> per 3,000 Btu/h of total input.

`140,000 Btu/h / 3,000 Btu/h = 46.667 in.²`

It also says that the opening cannot be "*less than the sum of the areas of all vent connectors in the space.*"

For example, If you had a water heater with a 3" round exhaust duct, and a furnace with a 5" round exhaust duct. The opening would have to be at least 26.704 in.².

`A = πr²`
`A = π * 1.5²`
`A = π * 2.25`
`A = 7.069 in.²`

`A = π * 2.5²`
`A = π * 6.25`
`A = 19.635 in.²`

`Total Area = 7.069 in.² + 19.635 in.²`
`Total Area = 26.704 in.²`

> ### Section G2403 (202) General Definitions
>
> **Connector, Chimney or Vent.** The *pipe* that connects an *appliance* to a chimney or vent.

It also says that the "*minimum dimension of air openings shall not be less than 3 inches*". So the opening for your installation would have to be one of the following sizes.

#### Rectangular

- 3" x 16"
- 4" x 12"
- 5" x 10"
- 6" x 8"

#### Square

- 7" x 7"

#### Round

- 8"

Comment: It's been a long time but this sounds close to me I don't remember all of it but there was a ceiling and floor level vent required to turn the air. When it was required . close to the vent size as I remember.