# Is the ventilation in my utility closet a construction mistake?

Tags: hvac, furnace, ventilation, central-heating, venting

With colder weather here in Northern Colorado (down to 22° F) my Goodman 90% efficiency furnace (GKS90453BX) came on for the first time in the (ca. 2005) home that I recently moved into.

The furnace was blowing only very slightly warm air. I checked the filter and it is fine.

However, I did notice that the closet containing my gas furnace and gas water heater was very, very cold. Upon further inspection, I noticed two 4" vent pipes that terminate in the ceiling on one end and to the exterior of the home on the other end. (See photos.)

Are these possibly artifacts from an optional 80% efficiency install? Can I close them off? The closet doors are bi-fold with a gap at the bottom, so I imagine there would be enough fresh air supply, but that is what I want to double check. Thanks!

---

UPDATE: I found the manual for the 40,000 BTU Water heater. It included the following instructions regarding combustion air availability. Provided I don't have a "tight construction" it appears that I can add combustion air via two additional 10" x 4" openings in the closet doors to communicate with the sufficiently volumetric adjacent inside air space.

> **Confined Spaces** 
>   Confined spaces are spaces defined as having less than
>   50 feet³ (1.41 m³) of space per 1,000 BTU (.29kw) per hour of input.
>
> **Unconfined Spaces** 
>   In unconfined spaces in buildings, infiltration may
>   be adequate to provide air for combustion, ventilation and dilution of
>   flue gases. However, in buildings of tight construction (for example,
>   weather stripping, heavily insulated, caulked, vapor barrier, etc.),
>   additional air may need to be provided using the methods described
>   above under CONFINED SPACES: All Air From Outdoors or SPECIALLY
>   ENGINEERED INSTALLATIONS.
>
> **All Air From Inside the Building**: The
>   confined space shall be provided with two permanent openings
>   communicating directly with an additional room(s) of sufficient volume
>   so that the combined volume of all spaces meets the criteria for an
>   unconfined space. The total input of all gas utilization equipment
>   installed in the combined space shall be considered in making this
>   determination. Each opening shall have a minimum free area of 1 inch²
>   (6.45 cm²) per 1000 BTU (.29 kw) per hour of the total input rating of
>   all gas utilization equipment in the confined space, but not less than
>   100 square inches (645 cm²). One opening shall be within 12 inches (31
>   cm) of the top and one within 12 inches (31 cm) of the bottom of the
>   enclosure.
>
> **All Air From Outdoors**: The confined space shall be provided
>   with two permanent openings, one commencing within 12 inches (31 cm)
>   of the top and one commencing within 12 inches (31 cm) from the bottom
>   of the enclosure. The openings shall communicate directly, or by
>   ducts, with the outdoors or spaces (crawl or attic) that freely
>   communicate with the outdoors.
>
> 1. When directly communicating with the outdoors, each opening shall have a minimum free area of 1 inch² (6.45 cm²) per 4000 BTU (1.2 kw)
>      per hour of total input rating of all equipment in the enclosure.
> 2. When communicating with the outdoors through vertical ducts, each opening shall have a minimum free area of 1 inch² (6.45 cm²) per 4000
>      BTU (1.2 kw) per hour of total input rating of all equipment in the
>      enclosure.
> 3. When communicating with the outdoors through horizontal ducts, each opening shall have a minimum free area of 1 inch² (6.45 cm²) per 2000
>      BTU (.6 kw) per hour of total input rating of all equipment in the
>      enclosure.
> 4. When ducts are used, they shall be of the same cross-sectional area as the free area of the openings to which they connect. The minimum
>      dimension of rectangular air ducts shall be not less than 3 inches
>      (7.5 cm).

[image: vent pipe photo 1]

[image: vent pipe photo 2]

[image: utility closet doors]

[image: closet overview]

Comment: Does the new furnace have an air intake of its own?  Are there any other fuel burning appliances in the closet? I see water lines, so I suspect there might be a water heater.

Comment: @Tester101 Yes, there is a water heater. Yes, the furnace appears to be vented. But dang is that closet cold. That can't be great for keeping the hot water hot, either. I added an overview pic. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: You could treat the closet as unconditioned space.  Insulate the closet, to separate it from the rest if the home.  Insulate the water heater, and furnace duct work, to reduce heat loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The furnace has the intake and exhaust of a sealed unit but the water heater is an old style open burner. The water heater requires the outside vent. The size of the vent is based on the BTU rating of the water heater. I would not close off the vent because this provides the fresh air for the water heater.

Comment: I agree, but it seems like the total vent area could be reduced. Any idea how to make the calculation?

Comment: Also, is a low-resistance flap an option? I faced the same dilemma with a rental home I had in Minnesota. The tenant kept blocking the vent as they didn't want to pay to heat the universe.

Comment: The water heater usually comes with the instructions on how many square inches it requires, I haven't installed a tanked unit in years, in older homes they did not require external venting but now do, I want to say that the external fresh air source had to meet the size of the flue 3 or 4" in most cases but it has been two long to remember for sure.

Comment: Thanks, @EdBeal. I'll try to find the install guide for the water heater. Will update and mark answered when I find out!

Comment: This [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/106994/33) describes how to calculate the size of the required duct.  But the references are old, and may have changed.

Comment: @EdBeal  l I updated my post with the installation instructions for the water heater. Marking yours as the answer here. Now I just need to figure out if my home is "tight construction" or not.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to determine if your home is "tight construction" is to close all the windows and outside doors in the house, hang a sheet of newspaper over that vent under the bifold door, and another over the gap at the bottom of the door, then watch the papers while somebody opens and slams the front door.

Also, in the more general case, for anyone else reading this, you can tell how tight your house is by closing all the windows and watching the water level in the toilet bowl as somebody slams the front door.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is helpful. However, I muddied the waters on this question with my update regarding tight construction, so I'll keep the original accepted answer to the original question.

Comment: I concur - I did not answer your original question.